# Como restringir acesso por usuário no Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Tenho um sistema que eu preciso restringir acesso em algumas áreas como a Administração do Usuário, por exemplo.
Eu não estou sabendo como pegar o usuário que está logado.
Sei que eu preciso restringir acesso ao arquivo e ocultar o menu.

```
<?php 
        $this->load->model('Usuarios_model');   
            if($usuario) { ?>           

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Usuários
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('usuario/visualizar_todos'); ?>">Visualizar</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('usuario/cadastrar'); ?>">Cadastrar</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </li>

        <?php  }; ?>
```

Comment: Você pode usar sessão para fazer isso. Se o usuário tentar acessar alguma página num controller admin, no __contruct desse controle vai ter a verificação de sessão admin, se a sessão não for válida, redireciona ele para login.

Comment: Você teria como me explicar com mais detalhes?
O meu está assim: 

public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logado'))
        {
            redirect('conta/entrar');
        }
    }

Eu não tenho muita experiência. Estou começando a aprender.

Comment: É exatamente isso, só que essa sessão pertence ao usuário. É só você criar uma igual para o admin, mas lembre-se de mudar o nome da sessão de admin, exemplo: admin_logado, isso vai de seu gosto.

Comment: Seria algo como:  
$this->session->userdata('adm_logado');
Eu quero ocultar o menu e bloquear o acesso de quem não é adm.
Não estou compreendendo.

Comment: Como está organizado a questão de login admin e usuário na pagina web ? Ambos usam a mesma página de login  ?

Comment: Cuidado ao bloquear páginas admin somnte usando ifs no menu, se eu tiver conhecimento da URL e digitar ela no browser, certamente eu vou conseguir acessar o recurso. Para evitar isso, você precisa criar um sessão admin e verificar se a sessão está ativa no __construct() do controller que está sendo acessado.

Answer (score 3):

Fabrício, você precisará configurar as variáveis de sessão, tente assim, crie um controlador de LOGIN.

```
public function entrar(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha', 'Senha', 'required|trim');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

                $formData = $this->input->post();

                $this->load->library('usuario');
                $user = new Usuario;


                if( $user->_check($formData['email'], $formData['senha']) == FALSE ) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("msg",'<p>Usuário / Senha não conferem</p>');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_userdata("logado", TRUE);
                    $this->session->set_userdata("userID", $user->getId());
                    redirect("dashboard");
                }
            }

        $this->load->view("login/v_header", array('pageTitle'=>'Entrar no Sistema | miPague', 'title'=>'Entrar no sistema'));
        $this->load->view("login/v_loginForm");
        $this->load->view("login/v_footer");
    }
```

No meu caso eu criei uma library para cuidar do usuário, mas pode ser um model também, fica por sua escolha. Minha library tem a função _check que tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
 public function _check($email, $senha){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model(array('m_login','m_clientes'));
        $CI->load->library(array('safe'));
        $user_mail = $CI->m_clientes->buscar_email($email);
        if($user_mail){
            $user_pass = $CI->m_login->check_user($user_mail->id);
            if($user_pass){
                $q = $CI->safe->valid_crypt($senha, $user_pass->senha);

                if($q == FALSE){
                    return FALSE;
                } else {
                    $this->setId($user_mail->id);
                    return TRUE;
                }
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Perceba que esta função carrega um comando chamado `$CI =& get_instance();`  isso me permite carregar outra library/model dentro dele diretamente usando apenas o comando `$CI->load->model('nome_model');`

A biblioteca safe, se encarrega de criptografar a senha do usuário e validar se a senha enviada pelo usuário confere com a cryptografada. Não postarei a minha rotina de criptografia pois ela tem particularidades que não desejo expor.

De qualquer modo, voltando ao Controlador de Login, há um `if` logo após o comando: `$user = new Usuário;` Este if faz o seguinte, SE a senha e o usuário não existirem, gera um erro na sessão usando o `$this->session->set_flashdata("var","mensagem aqui dentro")`

Caso exista o usuario e a senha for válida, seta a variável `"logado"` como `TRUE` e o id do usuário na variável de sessão `"userID"`

Depois para checar se existe na sessão um usuário ( userID ) basta usar o um dos seguintes comandos:

```
$this->session->userdata("userID");
// Ou usar
$_SESSION['userID'];
```

Agora basta usar comandos básicos do PHP como empty ou exists para mostrar/ocultar o que quiser no sistema, ou mesmo redirecionar.

Deixarei um link para um tutorial bem legal e completo de onde eu aprendi a fazer o sistema:

[Dicas Codeigniter - Tela de Login com Bootstrap e CI](http://www.dicascodeigniter.com.br/tela-de-login-com-bootstrap-e-codeigniter/)

Abraço...